# File.isFile java насколько этому методу можно доверять?

Tags: java

есть метод

```
int i = 0;
public void search(File file){
    File[] file1 = file.listFiles();
      try{
           for (File t : file1) {
            if (t.isDirectory()) {
             search(t);

            } else if(t.isFile()){
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

просто считаю файлы. сделал проверку жесткого диска - windows показал одно количество, программа другое, больше на штук 200. 
программа иногда выкидывает `NullPointerException`. Как понять кто показывает истинное количество файлов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доверять этому методу [можно](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()).

Какими средствами вы делали проверку жесткого диска?

Алгоритм рекурсивного обхода правильный. А `NullPointerException` у вас кидается на строке  `for (File t : file1)`, потому как `file.listFiles()` [может возвращать null](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()), когда `file` - не директория, а файл

Comment: выбор всех файлов, правая клавиша мыши, свойства и там в окне написано сколько папок и файлов